# subscribing to LoggedIn Observable not working

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I want to hide signin and signup links once I am logged in using a service in angular, but I am getting this error:
[image]

Here is my service code:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {BlogPost} from '../models/blog-post';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Channel} from '../models/channel';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BlogPostsService {

     private url = '/assets/data/';
     private loggedIn: Observable<boolean>;

     constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
     }
     getBlogPosts(): Observable<BlogPost[]> {
        return this.httpClient.get<BlogPost[]>(this.url + 'blog-post.json');
     }

     getChannels(): Observable<Channel[]> {
        return this.httpClient.get<Channel[]>(this.url + 'channels.json');
     }

     setLoginStatus(data: Observable<boolean>) {
        this.loggedIn = data;
     }

     getLoginStatus(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.loggedIn;
     }
}
```

Here is the signin.component.ts file submit code:

```
onSubmit() {
let users = [];
users = Array.from(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')));
const selectedUser = users.filter(user => {
  return user.email === this.signInForm.value.email
    && user.password === this.signInForm.value.password;
});
if (selectedUser.length === 1) {
  this.router.navigate(['/home']).then(r => {
    this.blogPostsService.setLoginStatus(r);
  });
} else {
  this.formError = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.formError = false;
  }, 2000);
}
}
```

Then in my header.component.ts I'm trying to get loggedInStatus but got the error message in the picture above. Please how do I fix this?
**header.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {BlogPostsService} from '../services/blog-posts.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    templateUrl: './header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  loggedIn;

  constructor(private blogPostsService: BlogPostsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loggedIn = this.blogPostsService.getLoginStatus()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.loggedIn = data;
        console.log(this.loggedIn);
    });
 }

}
```

Comment: you are return a boolean but not an Observable

Comment: create a subject instead then convert it to Observable

Answer (score 0):

In your `BlogPostsService`  service `loggedIn` is not an observable variable, you just given the type as Observable.

You can directly access the value without subscription,

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loggedIn = this.blogPostsService.getLoginStatus();
    this.loggedIn = data;
    console.log(this.loggedIn);
  }
```

If you want to do the subscription, Then you have to do a change in `BlogPostsService`,

import `of` operator from rxjs,

```js
 getLoginStatus(): Observable<boolean> {
    return of(this.loggedIn);
  }
```

Comment: but the signin and signup links did not hide. Please what do I do to hide and show it?

Answer (score 0):

1.In your service convert `loggedIn` to a subject or an behaviour subject

2.And return it as an observable like this

```
private loggedIn: Subject<boolean>;

getLoginStatus():Observable<boolean>{
   return this.loggedIn;
}

setLoginStatus(data:boolean) {
    this.loggedIn.next(data);
}
```

3.And finally you can access `loggedIn` in your header.component.ts like this

```
loggedIn$:Observable<boolean>
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loggedIn$ = this.blogPostsService.getLoginStatus();
}
```

4.You can use `loggedIn$` in your template using an async pipe no need for an subscription

```
<h1 *ngIf="(loggedIn$ | async)">Signed In</h1>
```

Comment: **Got this error:**  core.js:6241 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
    at BlogPostsService.setLoginStatus (blog-posts.service.ts:27)

Comment: I have been able to figure out what to do. Your code is correct just loggedIn variable should be declared like an object. Like this:

private loggedIn = new Subject<boolean>();

Thank you.

Comment: sorry i didn't initialise the subject correctly.Glad you cloud figure it out